# Building a query in PDO with parameters for table name

Tags: mysql, pdo

Is there a reason why this line doesn't work ?

```
$query = $pdo->prepare('DELETE FROM ___'.$arr['table'].' WHERE '.$arr['prefix'].'_Id=:id');
```

It should give me :

```
DELETE FROM ___Blog WHERE BLG_Id=7
```

I'm trying to built a query based on datas received.

Thanks.

Comment: We don't know why your PHP running your code on your server doesn't work. You PHP does.

Comment: "datas received" from where?